# C# split string containing quotation marks and backslashes

Tags: c#

I'm trying to split a string in C#, splitting at

```
\": {
```

My normal way is to use \ to escape characters but

```
" \\\": {"
```

Doesn't seem to work as intended

Comment: Can you post an example of what the string looks like before splitting and what you would like the resulting split strings to look like? And what code you have tried so far that hasn't worked as you'd like. Your current question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Hi sure
the string looks like

    \"2\": {      \"avgHighPrice\": 186,      \"highPriceVolume\": 20642717,      \"avgLowPrice\": 182,      \"lowPriceVolume\": 7827296    

I'm trying to get just the ID part (2) by removing the things to the right of it

Comment: That looks like JSON - there are LOTS of tools to process it that will work better than `String.Split`;  Parse it to get just parts of the data

Comment: Ah okay, could you give some examples please?

Comment: That string: `\"2\": { \"avgHighPrice\": 186, \"highPriceVolume\": 20642717, \"avgLowPrice\": 182, \"lowPriceVolume\": 7827296` is a C#-encoded version of `"2": { "avgHighPrice": 186, "highPriceVolume": 20642717, "avgLowPrice": 182, "lowPriceVolume": 7827296`.  You are seeing the back-slashes because you are looking at it in the debugger (likely).  Instead of doing that, hover over the string (in the debugger) and press the magnifying glass (/view) icon.  You'll see an unencoded version of the string.  As @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp has pointed out, that's a JSON fragment - treat it as one